# Iterating user-defined class objects inside a pyspark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

I am reading data from csv and converting that data into a python class object. But when i try to iterate over that rdd with user-defined class objects, I get errors like,

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.User'>: attribute lookup User on __main__ failed
```

I'm adding some part of the code here,

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.user_id = line[0]
        self.location = line[1]
        self.age = line[2]

def create_user(line):
    user = User(line)
    return user

def print_user(line):
    user = line
    print(user.user_id)

conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("exercise_set_2").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
users = sc.textFile("BX-Users.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(";"))  
users_objs = users.map(lambda entry: create_user(entry))
users_objs.map(lambda entry: print_user(entry))
```

For the above code, I get results like,

```
PythonRDD[93] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43
```

CSV data source URL(Needs a zip extraction): [HERE](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/BX-CSV-Dump.zip)

**UPDATE:**
changing the code to include collect will result in error again, I still have to try with Pickle. I never tried that one before, If you anyone have a sample, I can do it easily.

```
users_objs = users.map(lambda entry: create_user(entry)).collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found an explanation. **Storing classes in separate files will make the classes picklable automatically**. So I stored the User class inside user.py
and added the following import into my code.

```
from user import User
```

contents of User.py

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.user_id = line[0]
        self.location = line[1]
        self.age = line[2]
```

As mentioned in earlier answer, I can user collect(an RDD method) on the created User objects. So the following code will print all user ids, as I wanted.

```
for user_obj in users.map(lambda entry: create_user(entry)).collect():
    print_user(user_obj)
```

Comment: That might work with a local configuration, but it won't work in cluster/client unless your nodes share an NFS mount.

Comment: This is a quick fix, But I will update my answer when I change the classes Picklable.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
def create_user(line):
    user = User(line)
    return user
```

directly in a map call, this means that the `User` class has to be accessible to your nodes. Typically this means it needs to be serializable/picklable. How would a node use that class, or know what it is (unless you have a common NFS mount or something)? That's why you have gotten that pickle error. To make your `User` class picklable, please read this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html.

Additionally, you aren't performing a `collect()` on your RDD, which is why you see `PythonRDD[93] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43`. It's still just an RDD, your data is out on the nodes.

Comment: UPDATED the question. I will try with Picklable and get back to you.